# Show Windows 10 toast from WinForm application

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to convert the c# code from below link into VB.NET and run it from a classic Windows form application:

[Quickstart: Sending a local toast notification and handling activations from it (Windows 10)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2015/07/08/quickstart-sending-a-local-toast-notification-and-handling-activations-from-it-windows-10/)

I installed the required NuGet packages and created the code below (please note I skipped the "action" section from the original c# code for now):

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


    Dim title As String = "Andrew sent you a picture"
    Dim content As String = "Check this out, Happy Canyon in Utah!"
    Dim image As String = "http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-01-71-81-permanent/2727.happycanyon1_5B00_1_5D00_.jpg"
    Dim logo As String = "ms-appdata:///local/Andrew.jpg"
    Dim conversationId As Integer = 384928

    ' Construct the visuals of the toast

    'Visual content
    Dim visual As New ToastVisual()

    Dim TitleText As New ToastText
    TitleText.Text = title

    Dim BodyTextLine1 As New ToastText
    BodyTextLine1.Text = content

    Dim InLineImages As New ToastImageSource(image)

    Dim LogoImage As New ToastImageSource(logo)
    Dim AppLogoOverride As New ToastAppLogo
    AppLogoOverride.Source = LogoImage
    AppLogoOverride.Crop = ToastImageCrop.Circle

    ' Add all content into toastcontent
    Dim ToastContent As New ToastContent
    ToastContent.Visual = visual

    'Arguments when the user taps body of toast
    ToastContent.Launch = New QueryString() From {{"action", "viewConversation"}, {"conversationId", conversationId.ToString()}}.ToString()
```

I understand the code can be more efficient but for understanding it I left it for now like this.

Now the problem is the next line:

```
Dim Toast As New toastnotification(ToastContent.getXml)
```

and

```
ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast)
```

I cannot declare Toast as a new toastnotification and ToastContent seems to miss the getXml function.

Also the ToastNotificationManager is nowhere to be found.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you import the appropriate namespaces as per step 2 in the "Sending a toast" section?

Comment: According to the documentation I just found on MSDN, the `ToastNotification` and `ToastNotificationManager` classes are both members of the `Windows.UI.Notifications` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add 2 references! (Win10)

1rst:
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Kits\10\References\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract\1.0.0.0\**Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd**"

and (if you want to attach to the events provided by the `ToastNotification` class)

2nd:
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Kits\10\References\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract\1.0.0.0\**Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract.winmd**"

And use `ToastContent.GetContent()` instead of `ToastContent.getXml()`